# C pointers: Assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, gcc-warning

When I compile this code with gcc 7.3.0, I get an "assignment from incompatible pointer type".

```
int intVar = 1;
char* charPointer;

charPointer = &intVar;
printf("%d", *charPointer);
```

So far so good. I can deal with it by doing the pointer assignment this way:

```
charPointer = (char*)&intVar;
```

Now my doubt is: how is the second  case different? I can still mess things up if I don't cast charPointer to int* when I, for example increment it by n or dereference it. So why does the compiler act differently in those two cases? Why should he care if pointer type does not match during an assignment? I would just like to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: The second case is not different. You're just telling the compiler explicitly "cast this pointer to a `char *`", whereas without the cast, it's unclear whether it was intentional or is a potential bug. The difference is that one compiles, and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the casual type change `int *` to `char *`, the compiler warns of potential pitfalls.  With a cast, the compiler assumes the coders know what they are doing.

---

In C, the various type of pointers can live in different places, have different sizes and be encoded differently.

It is very common for all *object pointers* (`int*`, `char *`, `struct foo *`) to share the same size and encoding, but, in general, that is not required.

In is not uncommon for *Function pointers* to be of a different size than *object pointers*.

`char *` and `void *` share the same size and encoding and character pointers point to data with a minimal alignment requirement.  Converting a non-`char*` object pointer to `char *` always "work".  The reverse is not always true. leading to *undefined behavior* (UB).

Converting to non-character pointer also risks anti-aliasing (the need for the compiler to keep track that changes of data via one pointer type is reflected in another).  Very strange *undefined behavior* can result.>
Better code avoids pointer type changes<sup>1</sup> and when needed, is explicit with a cast.

---

<sup>1</sup> Exceptions include when changing an object pointer to `void *` or form `void*` when there is no alignment concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer conversions are kind of dangerous.

If the pointer type your converting from is insufficiently aligned for the target type, you get UB (==undefined behavior; read up on what it is unless you have already) already at the conversion.

Otherwise, if you get usually get UB on dereferencing because C's [strict aliasing rules](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) require that you access objects through lvalue types sufficiently compatible with their effective type.

While the last paragraph doesn't quite apply to conversions to char pointers as char pointers can alias any type, the warning (compilers could make it a hard error too) is still useful because the conversion is still kind of dangerous.

```
printf("%d", *(char*)&(int){0xFFFF});
```

will get you only the first byte (it is endianness dependent whether that is the most significant one or the least significant one), printing 255 (if the implementation's `char` type is unsigned) or -1 (if it is signed).

```
printf("%d", *&(int){0xFFFF});
```

will get you all the bytes that are in an `int`.

If the compiler lets you assign to a `char *` from an `int *` with just a warning, it should behave the same as with the cast, but you do need the cast for your C to be conformant (and for the compiler to be silent about the conversion).

Comment: "printing 255 (if the implementation's char type is unsigned) or -1 (if it is signed)." --> leads to different results depending on endian.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike Holt says, it's not actually different, except that you have told the compiler "Don't worry, I mean to do this".

The compiler does worry because assigning to a pointer of a different type is usually not what you want to do.  Your code is telling the compiler "Treat the memory holding this variable as if it were holding a variable of a different type".  This is almost certainly platform specific behavior, and possibly undefined behavior, depending on the types.

Comment: The compiler does worry because the standard says that it *must* output diagnostics.